# how to get rid off fat on the side your chest

Tags: weightlifting

I am a male adult . I have done incline and standard bench presses for the past 2 yrs. from the front , my chest looks good, but from the side I can still see extra fat and it looks ugly. any recommendation on what type of exercise that will help me getting rid off this fat?

Comment: Are you doing cardio exercises (running, cycling, rowing, swimming, skipping) before weight training? That itself will help you get rid of the fat.

Answer (score 1):

You can't spot reduce fat. If you want to lose fat you need to look at reducing your calorie intake below your maintenance requirements.

Chest exercises like those suggested by @Aaronman will help change whats underneath the layer of fat to give it a more aesthetic shape. Cardio exercise, while good for many other reasons, is no better than resistance training for losing fat.

Focus on building some muscle in the areas you are least happy with, and eat less than your maintenance requirements while eating a healthy diet will help get you where you want to be - keep in mind that extra weight training may increase your dietary needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a pretty well known fact by now that you cannot get rid of fat on a spot. However you can make the muscle there look better giving the appearance of less fat.

**Good Chest Exercises For Bulking Are:** Dumbell Fly, Bench Press (Incline,Decline and Normal) and Dumbell pullovers.

Another good idea would be to do cardio to lose weight.

Comment: Thanks for the unexplained down vote random person, always very helpful